# Understanding the OpenCV Sample stereo_match.py code

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am trying to understand the OpenCV sample [stereo_match.py](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/stereo_match.py). The place where the mask, out_points, and out_colors are calculated is what I am not able to understand. The code related to that is given below:

```
mask = disp > disp.min()
out_points = points[mask]
out_colors = colors[mask]
```

Here, what I know is, the mask, points and colors are numpy arrays of size 555x641. When the above operation is done, the out_points and out_colors become 300000x3 arrays.

What is the logic behind this and how do you achieve this functionality in pure python(that is lets say points, colors and mask are normal arrays, and i need to do the above operation with out using numpy and calculate the out_points and out_colors)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain the code:

```
mask = disp > disp.min()
```

Here mask is an 2D array with the same height and width as disp, but all values are stored as boolean. Each value from disp is calculated from the logic statement: x > disp.min()

```
out_points = points[mask]
out_colors = colors[mask]
```

These arrays are all the values from points and colors that were stored as True in the mask-array. As your image is 555x641 = 350k pixels, 300k arrays are within the size. As color images have three layers, the 300k x 3 makes sense.

You can do these operations without numpy, but I guess it will slow down your code a bit. If you have other questions, please ask!

Comment: Yes I was able to understand that, the out_points and out_colors are calculated in that manner, but now what I am trying to figure out is how the arrays have changed from 555x641 to 3000000x3 arrays. If the values for the out_points and out_colors are calculated if the mask value was true then, it should be arrays of size less than 555x641, right?? Is there a pure Python code that you can explain with?? Thank you

Comment: are you sure that it is 3M, not 300k? If it is 3M then I agree it is strange.

Comment: Yes it is 300K not 3M, sorry. I experimented with numpy.ndarrays and I tried to redo the same operation. What I understood was that if two arrays of same dimensions are taken and the above operation is done, it will create a 1D array. But the thing is points is 3D array and mask is 2D, the out put given is a 2D array. When I tried the same in the experiment, it gives me a "axis out of bound" error which is very strange.

Comment: Do you use a color image as input? Remember, those have three layers. RGB

Comment: Yes, it is a color image.

Comment: Then your image is a 3D array of size 555x641x3, thus the 3 columns

Comment: Is there a way to extract the color values?

Comment: sure. As a normal array operation: img[x][y][l] where l is the layer. blue: 0, green: 1, red: 2. Look here: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html

Comment: I see, well I will check it out. Now I need to find a way to extract them using nodejs-opencv(which is off-topic for this post). Thank you.